# How to calculate 95% Confidence Interval for binomial data when there are replicates

Tags: confidence-interval, repeated-measures, binomial-distribution

I would like to calculate the 95% CI for my binomial data.  The set up is that I have 20 devices, each measuring the *same* standard three times. The data are binomial and come out as Found/Not Found (1,0).  For the sake of argument lets say that each run comes up with 50% positive.  Using the 95% CI formula on some practice data (see below):

$ \hat p \pm z*\sqrt{ \hat p*(1- \hat p)/n }$

We would have a 95% CI of 0.5 +/- 0.11 (or spanning 28.1% thru 71.9%) and R1=R2=R3.

I could simply use *n*=60 and *p*=.5 and get a 95% CI of 0.5 +/- .12 (37.3%-62.6%).

However since each device is used 3 times measuring the same thing, I seems appropriate to account for my repeated measures?  Notice I have made the test data to be widely divergent, I do not think this is the case for my data.

I've used [Cochrane's Q Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochran%27s_Q_test) in the past to *test* for differences in paired data but in this case I want to **find** the global CI so I am not sure it is the right way of going.

How does one calculate the CI in this situation?

**Test Data**

```
Device  R1 R2 R3
   1    1   1   0
   2    1   0   0
   3    1   1   0
   4    1   0   0
   5    1   1   0
   6    1   0   0
   7    1   1   0
   8    1   0   0
   9    1   1   0
   10   1   0   0
   11   0   1   1
   12   0   0   1
   13   0   1   1
   14   0   0   1
   15   0   1   1
   16   0   0   1
   17   0   1   1
   18   0   0   1
   19   0   1   1
   20   0   0   1
```